# iPhone - Problem with UITextView

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextview

This is probably an easy thing to do, but I just can't figure it out - how do I end editing athe textview? how can I get the keyboard to disappear? or do I have to click outside it to make it go away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, a (to be honest) fairly simple question like this makes me wonder if you've tried reading the documentation, or searching on the internet.

Searching for "Apple documentation UITextView" gives you [this link](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html) to the class documentation. Similarly, [here is](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) the documentation for the UITextViewDelegate.

Searching for "UITextView simple example" gives you this [useful example](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/uitextview).

Searching for "UITextView dismiss keyboard", the first hit seems to [answer your question exactly](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-using-a-uitextview.html). (Although he dismisses the keyboard on a return key, which may not be what you want.) (Edit - it seems from your second comment it's exactly what you want.)

P.S. The people above are correct, if a little terse (understandably). You need to implement a UITextViewDelegate. In that delegate, if you want to hide the keyboard on a return key, implement shouldChangeTextInRange, look for a @"\n" and resign first responder if you get it. Alternatively, add a "Done editing" button to your UI, and resign first responder if the user presses it.

Comment: yep, google.com -> http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-using-a-uitextview.html

Comment: SO is full of "fairly simple question[s]" and thank goodness for that!

Answer (score 2):

Very Easy:

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

One way to end editing, tapping outside the textView, is not entirely trivial. Selecting other text views or text fields or activating a navigation control will trigger...

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

...on whatever object you've designated as the textView's delegate. You can trigger this yourself by calling...

```
- (BOOL)endEditing:(BOOL)force
```

...on the view that contains your text field.

Suppose I have a UITextView inside a UITableViewCell (inside a UITable). I want to enable editing to end by tapping the table. I could do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapTable)];
    [[self tableView] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [tapRecognizer release];
}

- (void)didTapTable
{
    [[self tableView] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Now whenever I tap my table, I end editing. And, as others have said, in `textViewDidEndEditing` I should be sure to call `[textView resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: I think that endEditing will call resignFirstResponder on the textView. The nice thing about endEditing is that you don’t have to know which textView is currently being edited. endEditing will find it for you and close the keyboard. From the documents.                     "This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign."

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

will make the keyboard disappear and editing end.