# UITextField - keyboard pops up when pressed

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

When using a UITextfield to enter information a keyboard pops up on the iphone simulator, the information with it says it will disappear again when return is pressed but it does not.

is there a line of code I need to add so that it will disappear again or is this a querk with the simulator??.

Carl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up your text field similar to this:

`UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

...

textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;`

you can see some of the basic options.  I suspect that you might be missing the `returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone`.  By default the return key will not behave this way.

Alternatively, if you `resignFirstResponder` the keyboard will go away, as others suggest.  It sounds like you want the Return key in the keyboard to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889925/iphone-problem-with-uitextview) Stack Overflow question out. It has everything you need to solve your problem.