# Hide keyboard and next line feature when using using text view

Tags: iphone

I'm using text view, for hiding keyboard i'm doing,

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

but by doing so even if i'm hitting enter button, keyboard gets hide. What to do to go on next line directly? I wanna implement next line feature.

Comment: Check this link, [iphone-problem-with-uitextview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889925/iphone-problem-with-uitextview)

Comment: I want for text view not for text field

Comment: If you want to allow the user to press "return" to go to the next line, why don't you just remove this code?

Comment: ok sorry I havnt read ur question carefully. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep a toolbar with done button just above the keyboard.

In default hide the toolbar. when the textView is selected show the toolbar with that doneBarButton.

On doneBarButton selector hide the toolbar again and resign the textview.